# Android Chrome - shortcut icons shown on Chrome home page

Tags: chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts

there are up to 8 shortcuts on the android chrome homepage. How do I specify which web pages I want them to link to?

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the shortcut manually. The workaround to add a shortcut is:

- Step 1: Remove one that you don't want.
- Step 2: Open a new tab, type/paste the URL of the webpage you want, and go to that site.
- Step 3: Repeat Step 2 once or twice more. The next type you open the homepage, the webpage shortcut will be added/listed.

Comment: Thanks, I've also found out that it won't add a shortcut if that page is bookmarked. Seems a flakey system.